# Laravel Self join Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, self-join

I am trying to execute a self join query in Laravel.    I am getting while i try to execute the same as raw query

```
  $data['d_meetings'] =DB::select("select t1.*,t2.* from `leads_followup_details` as `t1` inner join `leads_followup_details` as `t2` on `t1`.`leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id` = `t2`.`leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id` inner join `leads_enquiry_details` on `enquiry_id` = `t1`.`leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id` where  `t1`.`followup_meeting` = 'direct' and t1.followup_id<t2.followup_id and t1.followup_next_followup_date=t2.followup_date and `t2`.`followup_current_meeting` = 'direct'  and `enquiry_deleted` = 1 group by `t1`.`followup_id`");



$data['d_meetings'] = DB::table('leads_followup_details as t1')
        ->join('leads_followup_details as t2', 't1.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id', 't2.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id')
        ->where('t2.followup_id', '>', 't1.followup_id')
        ->where('t2.followup_id', '!=', 't1.followup_id')
        ->whereDate('t1.followup_next_followup_date', '=', 't2.followup_date')
        ->where('t1.followup_meeting', 'direct')
        ->join('leads_enquiry_details', 'enquiry_id', 't1.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id')->where('enquiry_deleted', 1)
        ->groupBy('t1.followup_id')->get();

but this is not working as my expectation .
```

Please help

Comment: is that SQL correct? you have `t1` and `t2` joined together on the same column

Comment: you loss the `groupBy`

Comment: Yes.. Sql works fine..I am getting expected result on sql console

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `->whereDate('t2.followup_date','=','t2.followup_next_followup_date')`
 doesn't match your SQL `and t1.followup_next_followup_date=t2.followup_date`

It might be easier if you write out the Laravel query in the same order as the SQL (and observe the re-added `->where('t2.followup_current_meeting', 'direct')`):

```
  $data['d_meetings'] = DB::table('leads_followup_details as t1')
                           ->join('leads_followup_details as t2',
                                  't1.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id',
                                  't2.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id')
                           ->join('leads_enquiry_details','enquiry_id',
                                  't1.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id')
                           ->where('t1.followup_id','<>','t2.followup_id')
                           ->where('t1.followup_id','<','t2.followup_id')
                           ->where('t1.followup_meeting', 'direct')
                           ->where('t2.followup_current_meeting', 'direct')                           
                           ->whereDate('t1.followup_next_followup_date','=',
                                       't2.followup_date')
                           ->where('enquiry_deleted',1)
                           ->groupBy('t1.followup_id')->get();
```

Comment: Sorry actually that I typed wrongly here, But i edited the question after posted question ..i am not getting correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$data['d_meetings'] = DB::table('leads_followup_details as t1')
                          ->select('t1.followup_id', 't2.followup_id', 't1.followup_next_followup_date', 't2.followup_date', 't2.followup_current_meeting', 't1.followup_meeting')
                          ->join('leads_followup_details as t2','t1.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id','t2.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id')
                          ->join('leads_enquiry_details','enquiry_id','t1.leads_enquiry_details_enquiry_id')        
                          ->where('t1.followup_id','<','t2.followup_id')
                          ->where('t1.followup_id','<>','t2.followup_id')
                          ->where('t1.followup_next_followup_date','=','t2.followup_date')
                          ->where('t1.followup_meeting', 'direct')
                          ->where('t2.followup_current_meeting', 'direct')
                          ->where('enquiry_deleted',1)
                          ->groupBy('t1.followup_id')->get();
```

I see you miss `t2.followup_current_meeting ='direct'`